# jQuery Validator: If fieldB is valid ignore one rule for fieldA

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 fields that need to be related but I am not sure if using a group is a valid method for this type of problem.

FieldA is an email address field. That field has 3 rules: require, email and uniqeEmail (a custom rule that checks if the email address is already in our database).

FieldB is only displayed if uniqueEmail returns false. FieldB has a uniqueUsername (a custom rule that checks if the username is already in our database).

**Here is my problem:**

If FieldB passes uniqueUsername and as long as require and email are satisfied for FieldA I want to label FieldA is valid for the UI display and also for when the form is submitted.